# How to get root of variations by client OM (JS)?

Tags: list, client-object-model, variations

Let say I have sub-sites on my "main site" (which is not root of site collection), like Home sub-site, About, Contact. The "main site" is actually language variation of another site. In another words I have structure like this

```
 - http://mysite -> this is root SPWeb
 - http://mysite/de-de -> this is "root variation"
 - http://mysite/de-de/Lists/myList -> list I'd like to get
 - http://mysite/de-de/Home/History -> sub-site in de-de variation from where I'd like to get "myList"
```

What I'd like to do is something like following

```
var rootOfVarSPWeb = SP.ClientContext.get_current().get_web().get_rootOfVariation()

//get the list
//do other stuff in root of variation
```

EDIT: Question is for SharePoint 2013.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It actually depends what version of SharePoint is used.

### How to retrieve Variation Labels via CSOM?

Since variations labels are stored in a Hidden List (MOSS 2007, SPS 2010/2013) we could retrieve it via CSOM (ECMAScript) as demonstrated below:

```
function getVaritationLabels(OnSuccess,OnError){
    var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var rootWeb = ctx.get_site().get_rootWeb();
    var webProperties = rootWeb.get_allProperties(); 
    ctx.load(rootWeb); 
    ctx.load(webProperties);
    ctx.executeQueryAsync(
      function() {
         var varLabelsListId = webProperties.get_item('_VarLabelsListId');

         var labelsList = rootWeb.get_lists().getById(varLabelsListId);
         var labelItems = labelsList.getItems(SP.CamlQuery.createAllItemsQuery());

         ctx.load(labelItems);
         ctx.executeQueryAsync(
            function() { 
               var variationLabels = [];

                var e = labelItems.getEnumerator();
                while (e.moveNext()) {
                    var labelItem = e.get_current();
                    variationLabels.push({
                        'IsSource': labelItem.get_item('Is_x0020_Source'),
                        'Language': labelItem.get_item('Language'),
                        'Locale': labelItem.get_item('Locale'),
                        'Title': labelItem.get_item('Title'),
                        'TopWebUrl': labelItem.get_item('Top_x0020_Web_x0020_URL')
                    });  
                }

               OnSuccess(variationLabels);
            },
            OnError
         );

      },
      OnError
    );
}
```

The function returns an array of Variation Label entries:

`IsSource` - Determines whether the Variation Label is set as the source label

`Language` - Returns the Language of the Variation Labe

`Locale` - Returns the Locale of the Variation Label

`Title` - Returns the title of the Variation Label, which is the unique string identifier of the label

`TopWebUrl` - Returns the URL of the top Publishing Web of the variation hierarchy of this label.

### Example: How to determine Variation Home?

Assume the following variation labels have been configured

[image]

where

`en-us` Variation Label corresponds to **Variation Home** (`Is Source` parameter is set to `True`)

then the following function will return the **Url of the variation hierarchy**:

```
function getVariationLabelSourceUrl()
{
    var sourceUrl = '';
    getVaritationLabels(
      function(variationLabels){
          for(var j = 0; j < variationLabels.length;j++){
              var variationLabel = variationLabels[j];
              if(variationLabel.IsSource){
                  sourceUrl = variationLabel.TopWebUrl.get_url();
                  break;
              }
          }
          console.log('Variation Label Source Url: ' + sourceUrl);
      },
      function(sender,args) {
        console.log('An error occurred: ' + args.get_message());
      }
    );
}
```

P.S. The demonstrated code samples been tested with SharePoint 2013